# How can I execute a cmd line command passing excel data as an argument?

Tags: excel, cmd, vba

We have a large list of user IDs in excel and would like to be able to click the user ID and have it execute the following command and display the results:  `net user /domain <user ID>`

I would imagine that call shell is the correct way to go... I'm just not familiar with using VB and excel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sub. This sub works for general DOS/batch command.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
       'Call Shell("CMD.EXE /c " & Target.Value)
       Call Shell("cmd.exe /c net user /domain " & Target.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

***Assuming your `User Name's` are in `Column A` Double click on any cell which have User Name then press `ENTER` or `TAB` key***

This is a screenshot which working 100% (For your clarification).
[image]

Comment: This seems to be working but the window closes before I can  read the output.  Is there a way to keep the window open or pipe the output to a file called <userID>.txt?

Comment: Nevermind,I was able to get the pipe to a file to work.

Comment: Yes you can show output in console. then use this line `Call Shell("cmd.exe /k net user /domain " & Target.Value, vbNormalFocus)` The parameter `/k` will wait window and `vbNormalFocus` will focus the `Command Prompt` tool. Let me know is it work for you or not. @digital_alchemy

Answer (score 0):

You could hook it into the selection change event of the worksheet, the code would sit in the worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then 'assuming your ID's are in column A
        Call Shell("cmd.exe" & "rest of your command")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and it's giving me a Run-time error 53 saying the file can't be found.  here is the code: `Call Shell("cmd.exe" & "net user /domain")`

Comment: What happens if you leave out the "cmd.exe", also currently you don't have an ID in the call shell.

Comment: If i remove the "cmd.exe" it looks like it passes the "net user /domain" command to the domain controller when I click a user ID.  I want it to pass the value of the currently selected cell as the user ID, how would I do that?